# Setting up Samba Shares with users that have different read/write permisions

Tags: server, permissions, samba, users, shared-library

I have just set up a Samba Server and setting up my shares, I have a Media Share that looks like this in the config file.

```
[Media]
 comment = Media
 path = /Media
 browsable = yes
 read only = no
 valid users = oliver, henry, carey, deb, guest
```

What I want is "henry, carey, deb, guest" to be read only and "oliver" to have read and write

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two entries in the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Add those lines:

```
[Media]
 comment = Media
 path = /Media
 read only = yes
 browseable = yes
 public = no
 valid users = henry, carey, deb, guest

[Media]
 comment = Media
 path = /Media
 public = no
 read only = no
 browseable = yes
 writable = yes
 valid users = oliver
```

Restart the samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

You check your smb.conf for any syntax errors:

```
testparm
```

A simpler solution is to use some GUI app to do  the job. [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-configuring-samba/) a list of some apps to use.